# Use data from a different sheet for table using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to generate a file with quite a few formulas. From there, I want to create a table on another sheet. Everything is pretty straightforward until I want to use data from a different sheet for the table.

The documentation only shows examples of already having the data you need, and then passing that to the .add_table as the 'data' parameter.

What I am trying to do is this:  (Which is structured how the rest of xlsxwriter's formulas are.)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(stuff)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('File.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Summary Page')
data = f"'Sheet1'!$A$1:$D${len(df)}"
worksheet2.add_table(f'A1:D{len(df)}', {'data':data})
workbook.close()
```

This approach adds the new sheet, and creates a table the correct size.  But then fills in the "data"  with 'data' as a string down the first column with one character in each cell.

Is there a way to create a table referencing data from another sheet using xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 0):

`ExcelWriter` is (obviously) for writing Excelfiles.
If you want to read data from Excel after writing and saving it (did I get you right?!) use
`ExcelFile.parse` or `read_excel` to convert data to dataframe and write it again to Excel by `ExcelWriter`. Unfortunately xlsxwriter does not support appending, so you have to load and write all sheets again. Or just use the default `openpyxl` as engine. Could be omitted (as said: default) but to point out it is given in minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', usecols='A:B', sheet_name='Sheet1', index_col=0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
# shape our data here
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
writer.save()
```